# How do I find vertices without particular edges from a particular vertex in Gremlin?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I am using python to run my gremlin queries, for which I am still getting used to / learning. Let's say I have vertex labels `A` and `B`, and there can be an edge from `A` to `B` called `abEdge`. I can find `B` vertices that have such edges from a **particular** `A` vertex with:

```py
g.V()\
    .hasLabel("A")\
    .has("uid", uid)\  # uid is from a variable
    .outE("abEdge")\
    .inV()\
    .toList()
```

But how would I go about finding `B` vertices that have no such edges from a **particular** `A` vertex?

My instinct is to try the following:

```py
# Find B edges without an incoming edge from a particular A vertex
gremlin.V()\
    .hasLabel("B")\
    .where(__.not_(inE("abEdge").from_(
        V()\
        .hasLabel("A")\
        .has("uid", uid)
    )))\
    .next()
```

And that results in a bad query *(Not sure where yet)*, I'm still reading up on Gremlin, but I am also under time contraints so here I am asking. If anyone can help but just using `groovy` syntax that is fine too as it's not too bad to convert between the two.

Any explanations would be helpful too as I am still learning this technology.

### Update

I guess if this were a real-life question, and related to this website. We could ask (`A=Person`, `B=Programming-Language`, and `abEdge=knows`):

> Which programming languages does **particular person** `A` not know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you almost had the answer:

```
g.V().hasLabel("B"). \
  filter(__.not_(__.in_('abEdge').has("A","uid",uid))). \
  toList()
```

I prefer `filter()` when using just a single `Traversal` argument, but I think you could replace with `where()` if you liked.

Comment: This was insightful, but I believe not what I am after. I would like a list of `B` vertices that have no edge called `abEdge` from a __particular__ `A` vertex given by a `uid`

Comment: What are typical situations where distinguishing the use of `filter` or `where` is important?

Comment: both take a single `Traversal` as an argument and do the same thing, so the question of use is a bit of a question of preference when you're calling it that way. For me, I tend to prefer `filter(Traversal)` over `where(Traversal)` and only save `where()` for its explicit cases where filter won't quite cut it, like when referencing a step label: `g.V(1).as('a').out('created').in('created').where(neq('a'))`

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer and insight.

Comment: I would like to identify the has-node differently. So far I have used hasId('abc'). But I pass this very node earlier in the query and can store it with as('abc'). How would I use this information inside or instead of the has statement?